# How can I create a smooth dropdown effect for my navigation bar?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Basically, I am trying to create a navigation bar that has a smooth dropdown effect. I have already created the navigation bar, but am struggling to make the dropdown effect. I would like the dropdown effect to be shown when the user hovers over the tab in the navigation bar called "Works." When hovered, I would like there to be 2 separate tabs that the user can click to navigate. I would like the navigation bar's theme to remain consistent, such as the font, color, and scroll effect. How can I do this? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks. Here is my code.

```js
window.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
  var header = document.querySelector("header");
  header.classList.toggle("sticky", window.scrollY > 0);
})
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Hind', sans-serif;
}

html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

body {
  min-height: 200vh;
  background-color: #000;
}

h3 {
  color: #3F69CA
}


/* Navbar */

header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  transition: 0.6s;
  padding: 40px 100px;
  z-index: 100000;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

header.sticky {
  padding: 5px 100px;
  background: #F5F5F5;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

header .logo {
  position: relative;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #F5F5F5;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 2em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  transition: 0.6s;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

header ul {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

header ul li {
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

header ul li a {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #F5F5F5;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  font-weight: 500px;
  transition: 0.6s;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

header ul li a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

header.sticky .logo,
header.sticky ul li a {
  color: #000;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>repl.it</title>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <a class="" href="#"></a>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#home">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#about">About</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#works">Works</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#test">Test</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </header>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I would use bootstrap and something like this in the css.  #works-submenu:hover > #works-menu {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 0;
 }

Answer (score 0):

Try css animation. See if this helps:
https://codepen.io/vajirkar/pen/jOrZaOg

Key part of the css is:

```
.container {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}

.menuPanel {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: coral;
  animation: slideOut 600ms;
  z-index: -10;
}

@keyframes slideOut {
0% {
    top: -150px;
}
100% {
    top: 0px;
}
}
```